# How to bind onClick to li and button inside it using react js

Tags: reactjs

[image] 1. on click of list user should see details of list
 2. on click of remove icon user will be displayed with remove button inside li and in this case point1(mentioned above should not get execute)
 3. on click of remove button list should be executed

```js
var ListComponentWithButton = React.createClass({
  
  getInitialState: function () {
    return {
      'isDelete' : false
    }
  },
  chooseProfile:function (val) {
  //should be executed when user click on li on normal scenario
    console.log('choose',val);
  },
  onDeleteClick: function(val){
  //executed while rendering
  //but it is supposed to be executed on click and onclick is not triggering this function
    console.log(val);
  },
  toggleDelete: function () {
    this.setState({
      'isDelete' : !this.state.isDelete
    })
  },
  render: function(){
  var List =[];
  var ListSource = [{
                    "alias": "John Player Peter England",
                    "id": "1"
                },{
    "alias": "John Player Peter England2",
                    "id": "2"
    }]
  ListSource.map(function (val, index) {
      List.push(
        <li key={index}  onClick={this.chooseProfile.bind(null,val.id)}>
          <div className="profile_list_row">
            <p className="initial">{val.alias}</p>
            <p className='profile_row_icon'>
                <span className="fontcon-arrow-right"></span>
            </p>
            <p className='remove'>
     <button onClick={this.onDeleteClick(null,this.props.val.id)}>
    <span>Remove</span>
     </button>
    </p>
          </div>
        </li>
      );
    },this)
    return (
      <div>
  <ul>
   {List}
  </ul>
  <div>
   <div>
    <div>
      <button className={' '+(this.state.isDelete ? 'hide':'show')}>
     <span>Add List</span>
      </button>
      <button className={' '+(this.state.isDelete ? 'hide':'show')}onClick={this.toggleDelete}>
     <span>Remove list</span>
      </button>
      <button className={' '+(this.state.isDelete ? 'show' : 'hide')} onClick={this.toggleDelete}>
     <span className="pad-l10">Done</span>
      </button>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
   </div>
    )
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have made a small correction and delete function got triggered on click.earlier <button onClick={this.onDeleteClick(null,this.props.val.id)}>
    <span>Remove</span>
     </button> and i changed as  <button onClick={this.onDeleteClick.bind(null,this.props.val.id)}>
    <span>Remove</span>
     </button>

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you provide to your elements as an event handler is not a function but what your function returns, since you call it.

For instance :

```
// You have not provided a function but instead
// you are calling a function
<button onClick={this.onDeleteClick(null,this.props.val.id)}>
  <span>Remove</span>
</button>
```

should be

```
// I have provided a function
<button onClick={event => this.onDeleteClick(event.target.value)}>
  <span>Remove</span>
</button>
```

ES5

```
// I have provided a function
<button onClick={ function(event){ 
  this.onDeleteClick(event.target.value) }
} }>
  <span>Remove</span>
</button>
```

Comment: Hi FurkanO, I am using ES5 and not ES6. could you please edit your ans for ES5. Because oClick is event handler and OnDeleteClick is function and I do not have clue how to bind it

Comment: Thank you. I added comment to my question. I bind a method instead of simply mentioning and it works !!!

Comment: Cool! Happy coding then